# Is There A Facility To Submit Useful Articles

Tags: support, article

I just implemented some functionality in a rails application I am working on that I thought might make a useful "How To" article. I'm wondering if I can do this on SO as there are some questions (old, and already answered) similar to what I've done.

I figured it might help out people looking for similar info.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is create a question and give a self-answer for it that covers what you want to express.  Just make sure that it would qualify as a good question even if you didn't have the answer ready.

Comment: In particular, SO is not eHow. So your question couldn't be "What are the steps to achieve *this* task?", because that would have been closed due to "lack of minimal knowledge" or "too broad".